# disable lock screen in a different way in android

Tags: android

I am able to disable the lock screen when my Application is open, but my requirement is little different. As you know after few minutes the screen turns off, and you need to click the power button to wake up. So I just want to go straight to my Application when I click the power button - no swipe to unlock the screen. Is it possible in any ways. Please provide your thoughts.

The following code I have used to keep the screen ON all the time:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: any suggestions for this issue. please do share your comments.

Comment: No comments till now!!!! surprised....!